# How to achieve reliable db reads calls with concurrency

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

Consider you have the very simple table definition of:

```
CREATE TABLE first_name
(    
    id Integer NOT NULL,
    name varchar(10),    
    PRIMARY KEY id
);
```

Now consider you have two rows like:

```
id ,  name
1     Dan
2     Jack
```

Imagine you have X processes that read from time to time the `max(id)` value,
then decide what is the sequential id to be written as the new record.
The problem is when having multiple processes like that, while reading we can already have another id entered.

1. What is the best option to guarantee in `postgres` an atomic action of read latest id and then write the next one, when having multiple processes doing the same all the time?
2. I know we have the `Serial` type (like `mysql` autoincrement) which allows automatic management of field updates in a sequential manner, how will it perform when multiple processes won't have any lock mechanism applied and just the serial definition, is it sufficient? are we protected here for concurrency problem?

Example for the second declaration from point 2:

```
CREATE TABLE first_name
(    
    id Serial,
    name varchar(10),    
    PRIMARY KEY id
);
```

Comment: The whole point of `SERIAL` is that the database solves the concurrency issue for you.

Comment: @davidbak: can you link a reference from documentation? in mysql it works like that

Comment: [Here's a page from the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) which reminds you that not _every_ sequential number might appear in your sequence (because the sequence ids are generated even if the row isn't actually added to the table, e.g., if the inserting transaction is rolled back).

Comment: And [here we see you can also use `GENERATED AS IDENTITY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html), standard SQL.

Comment: Finally, [here we see _sequence generators_](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createsequence.html) a postgresql (only?) construct that lets you make your own integer sequences without tying them to an (identity) column.  It discusses the semantics.  These sequence generators are behind the `SERIAL` columns.

Comment: You **cannot** have the scenario you are outlining with SERIAL, the "locking" for it is internal to Postgres, note there **will be gaps** but never a duplicate. Your idea of Max()+1 is a virtual guarantee that you **will** get duplicates; the exact scenario you are trying to prevent.

Comment: What will be the gaps?

Answer (score 0):

1. To get the max just query the serial value:

   ```
      select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('first_name', 'id'));
   ```

   for example:

   ```
   clima=# CREATE TABLE first_name
   (
       id serial,
       name varchar(10)
   );
   CREATE TABLE

   clima=# insert into first_name(name) select 'Diego';
   INSERT 0 1

   clima=# select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('first_name', 'id'));

    currval
   ---------
          1
   (1 row)
   ```
2. Yes and No, Depends, have you transactions... with witch scope?

Comment: Please refer to the original questions

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of SERIAL is that the database solves the concurrency issue for you.

With respect to postgresql:

[Here's a page from the postgresql documentation (Data Types/Numeric Types/Serial Types)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) which tells you that `SERIAL` columns are built on *sequences*.

> Note: Because smallserial, serial and bigserial are implemented using sequences...

[Here we see *sequence generators*, `CREATE SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) a postgresql (only?) construct that lets you make your own integer sequences without tying them to an (identity) column. It discusses the semantics, which includes the property that not every sequential number might appear in your sequence (because the sequence ids are generated even if the row isn't actually added to the table, e.g., if the inserting transaction is rolled back).

> Because nextval and setval calls are never rolled back, sequence objects cannot be used if "gapless" assignment of sequence numbers is needed. It is possible to build gapless assignment by using exclusive locking of a table containing a counter; but this solution is much more expensive than sequence objects, especially if many transactions need sequence numbers concurrently.

(Also you can "cache" sequence generation but then you have issues with non-sequential sequence ids).

Finally, [here we see you can also use GENERATED AS IDENTITY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) to the same effect, standard SQL.

Comment: Sequences are nothing unique to Postgres. Oracle always had them and SQL Server also added them a few years ago.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - ok.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - i may have stomped on your edit because I was improving the answer myself.  Go ahead an reapply your edit.